# In dart how to let an isolate create instance of child class Object from different package?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I have a isolate which needs ClassParent kind of object. This isolate resides in PackageA.
I have another PackageB, which implements this in ClassChild.

Now I want my isolate to pick up instances of ClassParent kind at runtime, that too such instances resides in a different package.

#### PackageA

```dart
//packageA
class ClassParent{
 sayHello(){
   print("Hello");
 }
}

functionToRunInIsolate(SendPort sp){
  ClassParent obj1 = createAndGiveRunTimeImplementation();
  obj1.sayHello();
}
```

#### PackageB

```dart
class ClassChild extends ClassParent{
 sayHello(){
   print("Halo");
 }
}

main() async{
ReceivePort rp = ReceivePort();

  rp.listen((message) {
    print(message);
  });

Isolate i = await Isolate.spawn(functionToRunInIsolate, rp.sendPort);
}
```

Its must be noted that the implementation is in a completely different package.
`functionToRunInIsolate` should use Implementation from PackageB.

PackageA has no idea that which package will provide the implementation.
Its should pick up the instance base don configs passed into it.

Comment: Can you make a small example which reproduce your problem?

Comment: @julemand101 added example code